# There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request error

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

I've seen this question being asked many times on this site, but I've yet to find a fix to this.

Anyway, my laptop is a part of the company's (whose employee I am) domain. The laptop was given to me by the company, and before me was used by a colleague that had to leave.

The reason why they gave it to me was that I had to continue working on the project he's been working on (before his departure). This was mainly because we're on a thight schedule, and reinstalling the whole app / dependencies on my initial machine/account would have taken an unestimable amount of time. **I mention that prior to the blocker, I was working on his account.**

The IT folks closed his account though and since I was logged into the domain while this happened, I think I get the error mentioned in the post title. I'll probably be able to talk tomorrow or in a few days with the IT guys and they will unlock the account, but I since I really need to finish something by tomorrow, I'm asking:

Is it somehow possible to log in with his account, bypassing the blocker mentioned in the post title? I also mention that I'm not currently logged in in the company's domain and I am writing this from my account.

Comment: Assuming that you know the previous employees' username and password AND assuming that you've logged onto his/her account before AND assuming that logon credential caching hasn't been disabled you should be able to disconnect the laptop from the network and login with the cached credentials of the previous employee.

Comment: Yeah, he gave me the credentials. Yes to the second thing as well and I guess (not sure) it's a yes to the third. How do I disconnect it from the network though ?

Comment: Er, unplug it, perhaps.

Comment: If the account was locked while you were logged in and on the domain, there is your issue.

And the vote to close is likely because you are a user, and not the sysadmin, who you should be asking instead.

Comment: FYI, the downvote is probably because your question isn't appropriate for this site, as per the Help link at the top. This site is intended for people who administer and manage IT systems. Since you are talking about the "IT folks" as if they're another team, you're probably not one of them.

Comment: I never suggested I'm a sysadmin. I'm a user (developer) and I get blocked because I was unaware of this IT change that happened as I was unaware

Comment: So, then, read the Help link.

Answer (score 5):

That particular error message means that no domain controllers are able to evaluate your credentials.  If the account was disabled, the error message would state that.

I don't think it's ethical for us to help you circumvent your employer's security measures.  I also think it was proper of them to disable the credentials of a departed colleague, although the error message you're receiving doesn't reflect that.

Comment: I agree with you. It's funny because it was agreed upon by my superiors (for me to continue on his laptop) but the IT guys had no clue about it, and their immediate reaction was to close the account. And I'm being blocked by this now, after I turned my computer on.. when I can't contact anyone from IT

Comment: The error message sounds like you've disconnected the laptop from the network. But if the account's disabled, you're stuck. I appreciate the problem, but we're the people who lock accounts, so we don't help people get around those locks. Sorry.